# setBackgroundMessageHandler is working on android but not on IOS in react native

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, apn

**Background notifications are received on Android but not on IOS in react native.**

index.js

```
 messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (message)=>{
  console.log(message)
});
```

This is called before registering the component as is mentioned in a certain Github issues.

This problem arises after migrating to react native firebase v6.

Package versions:-

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.0.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.0.0"
```

AppDelegate.m

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>
static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif



#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

#import <Firebase.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  #ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
  #endif

  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyA19U0nRV9PKyWHz-252DKVkShrzooWt5Q"];
  [FIRApp configure];

  
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"Sociana"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  
  
  
  return YES;
}

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *) options {

   return [RCTLinkingManager application:app openURL:url options:options];
//return [self.authorizationFlowManagerDelegate resumeExternalUserAgentFlowWithURL:url];
 }

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}





- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo
                                                       fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
}


- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RNAppAuthAuthorizationFlowManager.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate,RNAppAuthAuthorizationFlowManager>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;
@property(nonatomic, weak)id<RNAppAuthAuthorizationFlowManagerDelegate>authorizationFlowManagerDelegate;

@end
```

The notification payload that I am sending through the REST API is:-

```
apns: {
      payload: {
        aps: {
          "content-available": "true"
        }
      },
      headers: {
        "apns-priority": "10",
      }
    }
```

I have used an external device for testing, enabled all the background modes and push notifications in xcode and also from the apple dev account.
Current xcode version is `12.4`

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the value of content-available in `apns` header to be 1 instead of "true":

```
"content-available":1
```